# Why was ISO10126 Padding Withdrawn?

Tags: padding

Wikipedia mentions ISO10126 Padding has been withdrawn, but doesn't say why. Also there were no news reports about this, as far as I can see.

Why was it withdrawn? Are there security flaws? Is there maybe a new version?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Indeed, [ISO 10126-1:1991](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=18113) and [ISO 10126-2:1991](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=18114) titled *Banking -- Procedures for message encipherment (wholesale)* have been withdrawn circa 2007.

The padding specified by ISO 10126 was adding random until the message has length 7 (mod 8) bytes, then adding a byte coding the number of bytes added (including that byte), making the length 0 (mod 8) and suitable for DEA/DES block encryption. The rationale for adding a little randomness is dubious at best; it creates a [subliminal channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subliminal_channels), for no clear advantage.

I conjecture that the rationale of the withdrawal is *not* the padding algorithm, but rather the use of single-DEA/DES (56 bit key), which is clearly obsolete and insecure; and availability of other standards for the same purpose.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the standard does not even specify *random* bytes, but bytes which can have any value. I can look it up at work if anybody is interested. As the receiver has no way to check for randomness, it does not make much difference though. Note that PKCS 5/7 padding is compatible when *sending* bytes. Of course, you cannot asume PKCS 5/7 padding when receiving bytes as validating any padding byte except the last one may fail.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What do you mean by 'The rationale .. is dubious at best'? Does it have any drawbacks compared to PKCS5?

Comment: @Dexter: I mean that arguably, the benefit of having some random/unspecified bytes added (depriving an attacker of knowledge on plaintext) is outweighed by the drawbacks. In particular, these bytes could become (malignantly or by accident) a [subliminal channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subliminal_channels) leaking sensitive information, e.g. some of the key, or some of the plaintext.

Comment: I'm intrigued by this, wouldn't the fact that two identical plain-texts will have the identical cipher-texts leak information too? (the fact that they are identical) Or should this simply be combated by perturbing the message?

Comment: @roe: known plaintext is to be assumed anyway in the context of use of the ISO 10126 standards; therefore that must nbe handled and there can't be much danger is adding a little more vulnerability in that case. On the other hand there IS danger in sending nobody-cared-to-check-what-exactly out in the wild. Also, for a message of $8k+7$ bytes, ISO 10126 adds no random padding, thus does not help.