# Is there a standard prefix random padding scheme?

Tags: block-cipher, reference-request, padding, standards

Is there a standardized padding scheme which is prefix instead of postfix
and that uses random bytes except for the first byte which would be the
length of the padding?

Comment: [universal padding](https://xkcd.com/927/)

Comment: can't you apply a generic standard padding just to the front (like PKCS#7)?

Comment: Why would you want to use such a padding?

Comment: @CodesInChaos to make it hard for people to guess what was used to pad the message.

Comment: @UnixJunkie And why is that useful? I don't see the point, assuming you're using semantically secure encryption. It sounds a bit like you're trying to shoehorn the padding into the role of an IV.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I don't assume anything. ;)

Comment: You could use ISO10126 in reverse. But I doubt anybody standardized such a padding, because I don't see any advantage of padding in-the-front instead of padding in-the-end. Even randomized padding in the end has fallen out of favour, since it doesn't achieve anything that an IV doesn't already achieve.

Comment: Could be somewhat useful for "stealing" IV bits for the message in CBC, but using it securely would be difficult.

Answer (score 2):

I know of no standard like that and also doubt it exists.

It would have [similar disadvantages](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1932/13625) as random padding at the end, which is no longer in use: subliminal channel, consumption of randomness which may be expensive. Additionally, it would require knowing the message length in advance, which is a practical limitation.

Comment: Ok for the subliminal channel. For randomness, a CSPRNG can be used. Implemented properly, it would not require knowing the message length in advance but maybe prepend a full random block to messages which are composed of only full blocks.

Comment: @UnixJunkie, even a CSPRNG takes time to generate randomness, compared to deterministic padding which takes a few cycles to verify. Regarding message length, unless you know it (modulo block size) you do not know how the block boundaries will fall, so you can't start encrypting.